# Can't find class [org/drinkless/td/libcore/telegram/TdApi$Object]

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am getting this error "Can't find class [org/drinkless/td/libcore/telegram/TdApi$Object]" but I haven't used this class anywhere in my project.

I haven't used that class anywhere.
But i am getting the above error

Can anyone please let me know how to solve the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1.Build->Clean Project and then try to rebuild the project, if that failed try the second

2.File->Invalidate Caches/Restart-> Invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Create new project and transfer the project. Or uninstall android studio and install it again

Comment: Uninstalled and installed android studio but till the same issue.

Comment: Try that if you can : Crete a new project and import only the libraries(build.gradle), no classes, after that compile them and execute the project, if that fails just try to eliminate one by one until the execution succeed and I hope you will  find the mysterious library that cause the problem.